# How to get All Dates in a given month in C#

Tags: c#, list, datetime

I want to make a function that take month and year and return `List<DateTime>` filled with all dates in this month.

any help will be appreciated

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Here's a solution with LINQ:

```
public static List<DateTime> GetDates(int year, int month)
{
   return Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month))  // Days: 1, 2 ... 31 etc.
                    .Select(day => new DateTime(year, month, day)) // Map each day to a date
                    .ToList(); // Load dates into a list
}
```

And one with a for-loop:

```
public static List<DateTime> GetDates(int year, int month)
{
   var dates = new List<DateTime>();

   // Loop from the first day of the month until we hit the next month, moving forward a day at a time
   for (var date = new DateTime(year, month, 1); date.Month == month; date = date.AddDays(1))
   {
      dates.Add(date);       
   }

   return dates;
}
```

You might want to consider returning a streaming sequence of dates instead of `List<DateTime>`, letting the caller decide whether to load the dates into a list or array / post-process them / partially iterate them etc. For the LINQ version, you can accomplish this by removing the call to `ToList()`. For the for-loop, you would want to implement an [iterator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dscyy5s0%28v=VS.80%29.aspx). In both cases, the return-type would have to be changed to `IEnumerable<DateTime>`.

Comment: Oh, I like the Linq version. That's nice. Very educational for a Linq newbie, thank you.

Comment: @Ani Great answer.  Is there a way to use the Linq syntax to get a range of dates, say from the first of a month to a specified date?
ie. Dates from June 1 -> June 20.

Answer (score 5):

Sample for pre-Linq Framework versions, using February 1999.

```
int year = 1999;
int month = 2;

List<DateTime> list = new List<DateTime>();
DateTime date = new DateTime(year, month, 1);

do
{
  list.Add(date);
  date = date.AddDays(1);
while (date.Month == month);
```

Comment: I guess `date.Month == 2` should have been `date.Month == month` :)

Comment: Man, this is best answer I came across even after 6 years you posted this. So simple so readable, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I am sure there might be better ways to do this. But, you could use this:

```
public List<DateTime> getAllDates(int year, int month)
{
    var ret = new List<DateTime>();
    for (int i=1; i<=DateTime.DaysInMonth(year,month); i++) {
        ret.Add(new DateTime(year, month, i));
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
    public List<DateTime> AllDatesInAMonth(int month, int year)
    {
        var firstOftargetMonth = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
        var firstOfNextMonth = firstOftargetMonth.AddMonths(1);

        var allDates = new List<DateTime>();

        for (DateTime date = firstOftargetMonth; date < firstOfNextMonth; date = date.AddDays(1) )
        {
            allDates.Add(date);
        }

        return allDates;
    }
```

Iterates through the dates from the first of the month you want through to the last date that's less than the first of the next month.

PS: If this is homework, please tag it with "homework"!

Answer (score 0):

int year = 2024;
int month = 3;

int daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).