# How to get a list of week days in a month?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, datetime

[In this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849975/how-to-get-all-dates-in-a-given-month-in-c) it shows how to get all days of a month. I need the same thing, but I only want to list days of week (I want to exclude weekends).

How can I get a list of days of a month excluding weekends?

Comment: You have a lot of rep. Tell us what you have tried so far.

Comment: He is getting too lazy as the reputation goes up, you know, power corrupts.

Comment: @leppie: Have you never being on a problem that you couldn't solve, then you decided to ask for help and got the answer before any answers? This one was pretty much like it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Well, how about:

```
public static List<DateTime> GetDates(int year, int month)
{
   return Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month))
                    .Select(day => new DateTime(year, month, day))
                    .Where(dt => dt.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday &&
                                 dt.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday)
                    .ToList();
}
```

Comment: I missed that property. Thanks.