# How can I get total number of days in selected month with/without the weekends in WPF?

Tags: c#

I am hoping to find a way to get the total number of days in a month with and without the weekends using LINQ in my ViewModel. For example, September would count for 20 days without weekends and 30 days with the weekends.

I also have a datepicker binding to MDate and I have no idea were to start.

Can someone please suggest an easy method? I am just an amateur.

```
private DateTime _mDate = DateTime.Now;

public DateTime MDate
{

    get { return _mDate; }
    set
    {
        if (value == _mDate)
        {
            return;
        }  
        else
        {
            _mDate = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MDate");
            SetDaysInMonth();
        }

    }

}

private void SetDaysInMonth()
        {
            ???
        }
```

Thank you.

Comment: What on earth does an average Joe like you gain from leaving a useless comment like this?

Answer (score 3):

[DateTime.DayOfWeek](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek(v=vs.110).aspx) method could come handy, and [this answer by Ani](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3850003/2788979) shows how to get all days in a given month.

borrowing from the answer mentioned above:

```
public static List<DateTime> GetDates(int year, int month)
{
   var dates = new List<DateTime>();

   // Loop from the first day of the month until we hit the next month, moving forward a day at a time
   for (var date = new DateTime(year, month, 1); date.Month == month; date = date.AddDays(1))
   {

      if(date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday) 
      {
          dates.Add(date);
      }       
   }

   return dates;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping again Farzan. I have tried the abose and I get 2 error: Invalid expression term 'continue' and ; expected. What am I doing wrong. I just copied your answer.

Comment: Change the line containing `continue` to : `if(date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday) { dates.Add(date); }`.

Comment: Thank you for your time and help. I have tried the edited answer and I get the following message: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'year' of 'LocationViewModel.SetDaysInMonth(int, int)'. What can I do to solve this?

Comment: seems to me like you LocationViewModel requires a year parameter. I don't know what that model is, but if you'd like you could post it in your address and I'll take a look.

Comment: My model is an EF database-first that contains a partial class with: public System.DateTime Date { get; set; }. By address do you mean original post? Thanks!

Comment: yes, sorry, original post is what I meant. Hm.. to be honest I'm not sure why you are getting this error, what is the SetDaysInMonths method's definition ?

Comment: The definition is exactly your answer. I just changed GetDates to SetDaysInMonth. Thank you Farzan.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155848/discussion-between-farzan-mirheydari-and-icosmin).

Answer (score 2):

```
        int count = Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(2017, 10)) // year and month
                         .Select(day => new DateTime(2017, 10, day)) // year and month
                         .Where(d => d.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday && d.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday) // check each day for weekend
                         .ToList().Count;
```

Hope you need only the no of working days in a month

Comment: Thank you for the answer Kassapa. I like your simple solution but I was wondering if I could pass the _mDate parameter instead of the fixed date like the answer above. Do I need a base constructor? I get the following message: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter '_mDate' of 'LocationViewModel.SetDaysInMonth(DateTime)'. Can you please edit your post to help me out? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Find the number of days in month then enumerate and excluded Saturday and Sunday.

```
private static void SetDaysInMonth(DateTime mDate)
    {
        int numberOfBusinessDays = Enumerable.Range(1, DateTime.DaysInMonth(mDate.Year, mDate.Month))
                                     .Select(day => new DateTime(2017, mDate.Month, day)) 
                                     .Count(d => d.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday && d.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday); 
    }
```

Comment: Hello SMA. This seems exactly like the type of answer I was looking for. However I get the following error: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'mDate' of 'LocationViewModel.SetDaysInMonth(DateTime)'. That am I doing wrong? I've change _mDate to mDate and I still get the same message. Please advise.

Comment: How are you calling SetDaysInMonth method?

Comment: You need to pass DateTime as input parameter. If you want the number of days of the current month call SetDaysInMonth(DateTime.Now)

Comment: SMA, that's exactly what I need but I am too much of a beginner to fully understand how to pass that parameter. I've been researching all day. Do I need a base constructor? Can you please show me what do I need to change in order to pass that parameter. This is how I am calling the SetDaysInMonth method: public LocationModel()
{

    SetDaysInMonth();

}

Comment: I've manged to figure out what needed to be change. (mDate to MDate) but the result of the query is 0. Do you have any suggestions?